# Http4s Client Encode Entity as x-www-form-urlencoded Recursively

Tags: scala, circe, http4s, http4s-circe

I have a request like the following

```
val request =
    Request[IO](
      method = POST,
      uri = Uri.uri("..."),
      headers = Headers(
        Authorization(BasicCredentials("...", "..."))
      )
    )
    .withEntity(PaymentIntentRequest2(2000, "usd"))
```

I am looking [at the source code](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/1af3abe0c099a974a30d3c75beb047f8f17399a7/core/src/main/scala/org/http4s/Message.scala#L70) and it looks like the `withEntity` inherits the headers from the nested `EntityDecoder` so the code above defaults to `Content-Type: application/json`. Where as if I explicitly pass in `UrlForm` everything is fine.

Unfortunately the API I am hitting expected the data as `x-www-form-urlencoded` and given the complexity of the target API with all the different endpoints/requests I would like to find a way to encode the given case class as a form. What is the best way of doing that?

I have tried:

1. Explicitly specifying the `Content-Type` but this doesn't work because the inherited type takes priority
2. Building an implicit generic conversion from `Product` to `UrlForm` (extension method for now)

```
implicit class UrlFormEncode[+B <: Product](val u: B) {
    def asUrlForm: UrlForm =
      u.productElementNames
        .zip(u.productIterator)
        .foldLeft(UrlForm()) { (a, b) =>
          a.combine(UrlForm(b._1 -> b._2.toString))
        }
}
```

The problem here is `UrlForm` expects a string in both sides of the mapping. And if I just convert things with `.toString` it doesn't work because of nested typed for example:

```
ChargeRequest(Amount(refInt), EUR, source = Some(SourceId("...."))
```

Results in the following `json` which is not valid

```
{
  "currency": "EUR",
  "amount": "2000",
  "source": "Some(SourceId(....))",
  "customer": "None"
}
```

I tried `asJson` instead of `toString` but circe can not decide on the proper `KeyEncoder`

What is the right way of approaching this so the given `Product` is encoded down the stream ?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue and this is the way it worked for me.

From https://http4s.org/v0.20/client/

```
// This import will add the right `apply` to the POST.
import org.http4s.client.dsl.io._


val form = UrlForm(
      OAuthAttribute.Code        -> code,
      OAuthAttribute.RedirectUri -> callbackUri,
      OAuthAttribute.GrantType   -> "authorization_code"
    )

private def buildRequest(tokenUri: Uri, form: UrlForm, header: String): Request[IO] =
    POST(
      form,
      tokenUri,
      Header.Raw(CIString("Authorization"), header),
      Header.Raw(CIString("Content-Type"), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
      Header.Raw(CIString("Accept"), "application/json")
    )
```

And that's it. For some strange reason using `.withHeaders` didn't work for me, seems like they are overridden or so.

Comment: Sorry I am failing to see how this is the same problem. Where are you encoding a nested `Product` type here? The answer has a lot of undefined symbols, so I can't really tell. Is `code` a complex object?

Comment: For the problem, it doesn't matter, everything is around the Content-Type and how http4s defaults to `Content-Type: application/json`. Constructing the request as I did should solve the issue. In this way, the default header will be `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. I will try it this weekend. I need to re-extract a minimal example from my use case. Will accept the answer once I confirm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, and updating a bit the base information provided from @Juan Pablo Gómez Uribe I was able to request a token by using:

```
val request = POST(
    UrlForm(
      "client_id" -> "CLIENT_ID",
      "grant_type" -> "ANY_TYPE",
      "scope" -> "string1 string2 string3",
      "client_secret" -> "CLIENT_SECRET"
    ),
    uri"https://urlexample.com/oauth2/token",
    Headers(
       Header.Raw(CIString("Content-Type"), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
       Header.Raw(CIString("Accept"), "*/*"),
       Header.Raw(CIString("Accept-Encoding"), "gzip, deflate, br"),
       Header.Raw(CIString("Connection"), "keep-alive")
    )
  )
```